# Include permutations of nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, permutation

I have the following function to get the number of permutations (without repeating elements) of a list:

```
import itertools

def permutations_without_repetition(samples, size):
    return list(itertools.permutations(samples, size))
```

Which works fine for me as long as the list I provide doesn't contain nested lists. Itertools treats nested elements just as one whole element, and doesn't bother also generating permutations containing differently-ordered nested lists.

If I run `permutations_without_repetition([[1, 2], 3], 2)`, the only results I get are:

```
[([1, 2], 3), (3, [1, 2])]
```

I know this is the expected behaviour, but I would like the result to be:

```
[([1, 2], 3), (3, [1, 2]), ([2, 1], 3), (3, [2, 1])]
```

What's the easiest way to also return permutations that contain permutations of nested lists, to produce the result above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
def combos(d, c = []):
   if not isinstance(d, list):
      yield d
   elif not d:
      yield c
   else:
      for i, a in enumerate(d):
         for k in combos(a, c = []):
             yield from combos(d[:i]+d[i+1:], c+[k])

print(list(combos([[1, 2], 3])))
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2], 3], [[2, 1], 3], [3, [1, 2]], [3, [2, 1]]]
```

Shorter solution using `itertools`:

```
import itertools as it
def combos(d):
   if not isinstance(d, list):
      yield d
   else:
      for i in it.permutations(d):
         yield from map(list, it.product(*[combos(j) for j in i]))

print(list(combos([[1, 2], 3])))
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2], 3], [[2, 1], 3], [3, [1, 2]], [3, [2, 1]]]
```